# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException near ")"

Tags: java, android, sql, database

Can anyone see what is wrong with this code please, this is the error given:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near ")": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE scores(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , scoreName TEXT , );

```
public class MyDBHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "scores.db";

    public static final String TABLE_SCORES = "scores";
    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCORENAME = "scoreName";


    public MyDBHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORES + "(" +
                COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT  " +
                COLUMN_SCORENAME + " TEXT " +
                ");";

        db.execSQL(query);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS" + TABLE_SCORES);
        onCreate(db);
    }

    public void addScore(Scores score) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COLUMN_SCORENAME, score.get_scoreName());
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORES, null, values);
        db.close();
    }


    public void deleteScore(String scoreName) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + TABLE_SCORES + "WHERE " + COLUMN_SCORENAME + "=\"" + scoreName + "\";");
    }

    public String databaseToString() {
        String dbString = "";
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SCORES + "WHERE 1";

        //Cursor point to a location in your results
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        //move to first row in your results
        c.moveToFirst();

        while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
            if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreName")) != null) {
                dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("scoreName"));
                dbString += "\n";
            }
        }
        db.close();
        return dbString;
    }
}
```

Comment: i know this looks bad, i couldn't get it posted, please bear with me

Comment: You need a comma after `AUTOINCREMENT` to separate the definitions of the two columns.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, Accordingly to the stacktrace, he has an additional command before the closing bracket. I think that's the issue

Comment: I have added the coma after auto increment but it still crashes, how would i fix this additional command before the closing bracket @Blackbelt

Comment: you might want to leave a space between `scores(_id ` as well. E.g. `scores ( _id `

Comment: it helped thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem in Query for creating table (comma is missing after AUTOINCREMENT). Try this

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORES  + " ("
+ COLUMN_ID  + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
+ COLUMN_SCORENAME + " TEXT" + ");");
```